# How to to deal with temporary logic in apps

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Sometimes we add time-based temporary objects to our templates. Objects/texts that disappear when a certain date has arrived. After this date, the information should be hidden, but actually also be deleted. At this moment it's all hardcoded in the templates.

Are there any best practices to handle this usecase, by for example decoupling the temporary info from sourcecode?

Comment: You'll have to provide more specifics about what you're trying to do here. Can you dynamically generate your template parts?

Comment: Yes I can. I'm using in this case Laravel with Blade.